# Negative Lookahead: trying to match one word and negate following words

Tags: regex

I have a regex like

```
^.*\bfrost.*(?!flakes|snowman).*$
```

I am testing it against the following lines:

```
frosted flakes
frosty snowman
frost, jack
```

See [this Regex.101](https://regex101.com/r/rCzRjW/1/) demo.

I only want the third expression to match, but all three are matching.

[image: REGEX Try]

Comment: It is a good practice to paste text rather than snapshots. if you only want the third line to match you could use the comma in the regex to match better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the second `.*` into the lookahead, e.g.

```
^.*\bfrost(?!.*(?:flakes|snowman)).*$
```

Or

```
^.*\bfrost(?!.*flakes|.*snowman).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1P30QI/1)

In the original regex, the lookahead is located after a `.*` and whenever the lookahead returns false, the regex engine can backtrack and still match the string in another way, a location that is not immediately followed with `snowman` or `flakes`. When you put `.*` into the lookahead these two words do not have to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: @T.Hannah Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting the answer if it proved helpful.